# Why am I not getting better performance with numpy.searchsorted over bisect.bisect_left on a list of datetime?

Tags: python, performance, numpy

I've read that numpy's searchsorted is a faster binary search than python's bisect. More preparation is required with numpy.

I'm using a numpy.array of numpy.datetime64 objects. This performance test is similar to my use case - searching a list of about 1000 datetimes for a single target.

```
from bisect import bisect_left
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from random import randrange
from timeit import timeit

import numpy as np


def randdate():
    r = randrange(int((datetime.max - datetime.min).total_seconds()))
    return datetime.min + timedelta(seconds=r)


data = sorted(randdate() for _ in xrange(1000))
np_data = np.array(data, dtype=np.datetime64)

x = randdate()
np_x = np.datetime64(x)


def python_bisect():
    result = bisect_left(data, x)
    return result


def numpy_searchsorted():
    result = np_data.searchsorted(np_x)
    return result


time1 = timeit(python_bisect, number=1000)
time2 = timeit(numpy_searchsorted, number=1000)
print time1
print time2
print "bisect/searchsorted: {}".format(time1 / time2)
```

Still I'm seeing bisect twice as fast as searchsorted.

Comment: where are you sorting your data? those methods work only if lists are sorted.

Comment: numpy is faster at sorting in a whole array of values at once. When doing it as Python loop one by one there is much more overhead than for `bisect`.

Comment: plus you're not sorting the same data. Difficult to compare

Answer (score 3):

Some issues with your benchmarking:

1. Your input list / array should be sorted.
2. Single operations in a Python-level `for` loop are not a good measure of performance for NumPy: the second argument of `np.searchsorted` supports an array. Use this feature.
3. Use a larger number of inputs, e.g. `10**6` instead of `20000`.
4. Use `timeit` for reliable performance measurement.

Here's a demonstration:

```
N = 10**6

data = sorted([randdate() for _ in range(N)])
np_data = np.sort(np.array(data, dtype=np.datetime64).astype(np.int64))

def python_bisect():
    return [bisect(data, data[x]) for x in range(N)]

def numpy_searchsorted():
    return np.searchsorted(np_data, np_data, side='right')

%timeit python_bisect()       # 1.3 s per loop
%timeit numpy_searchsorted()  # 60 ms per loop
```

Comment: For my use case I want to do binary search with one target. I sorted my data and bisect is still slightly faster.

Comment: @DanielLeon, Sure, so use `bisect`. NumPy is suited for vectorised array-based calculations, it doesn't promise to speed up a *single* calculation.